# Google Maps Marker Animations is not woking

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This code working but when I mouse click each marker, Marker not Animation BOUNCE.

```
for(i=0; i<locations.length; i++) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][2], locations[i][3]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
                    icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(locations[i][5]),
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][1]);
            infowindow.setOptions({maxWidth: 500});
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
            animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE         

    }) (marker, i));

    Markers[locations[i][4]] = marker;                
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to bounce?  You aren't adding the BOUNCE animation to the marker. I would expect you are getting a javascript error on that code.

Answer (score 0):

set the animation in the click-callback:

```
return function() {
        //set the animation
        this.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);

        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][1]);
        infowindow.setOptions({maxWidth: 500});
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
```